# OSGI Valid Version Ranges

Tags: java, osgi

Currently I'm trying to implement OSGI Version Ranges (for a different topic, but I like the way they define version ranges). However I'm having a hard time to find the specific Definition of a Version Range in OSGI.

Unfortunately, the OSGI API does contain a Version class but not a VersionRange class. It seems like all OSGI Containers come up with their own interpretation of the (somewhat unfindable) Version Range definition.

Therefore I have several questions:

- If I used `versionRange=1.4.0`, would this map to Version >= 1.4.0?
- Is this a valid version range: `versionRange=[1.0.0,0]`: I'd say yes (version 1.0.0 up to any version), Eclipse implementation accepts it as a version but does not handle it correctly.

  - Would this be a valid versionRange aswell: `versionRange=[1.0.0,0)`?
- Where is the actual source of truth for all those questions? I seem to be unable to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version ranges **are** precisely defined in section 3.2.6 of the OSGi Core Specification. You're correct that there is no `VersionRange` class in the current API, though there will be in the next specification release.

OSGi framework implementations do **not** come up with their own interpretation of ranges; if you find a case where a specific framework interprets a range differently from section 3.2.6 of the Core Spec then please raise a bug against that framework.

To address your specific questions:

- Yes, `version=1.4.0` on an `Import-Package` (or `bundle-version=1.4.0` on a `Require-Bundle`) does map informally to "version >= 1.4.0".
- I believe that both of these version ranges are valid, BUT they will never match any version. E.g. first example will match only version `x` where `x >= 1.0.0` **and** `x<=0`. There is no value of `x` that can satisfy both of these requirements. So it sounds like Eclipse is behaving correctly... it should successfully parse the range string but never return any results.
- As already mentioned, the "source for truth" is section 3.2.6 of the OSGi Core Specification.... page 29 if you are reading the R4.3 version of the document.

Answer (score 8):

So, to answer your concrete questions in order:

> - If I used versionRange=1.4.0, would this map to Version >= 1.4.0?

Yes. This is exactly the way spec says it should be interpreted (see below).

> - Is this a valid version range: versionRange=[1.0.0,0]

Yes, it is a valid range, but it will not evaluate to what you seem to be expecting.
It effectively evaluates to an empty set of versions, so no version will match this expression.

> - Would this be a valid versionRange aswell: versionRange=[1.0.0,0)?

Same as above -- it is a valid version range, but it will evaluate to an empty set.

> - Where is the actual source of truth for all those questions? I seem to be unable to find it

The specs are available on [OSGi Alliance's](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) home page from: 
http://www.osgi.org/Release4/Download (for R4 specs)

Below is an excerpt from the OSGi R4 core specification that covers the version ranges:

> **Version Ranges**
>
> A version range describes a range of versions using a mathematical interval notation. See [31] Mathematical Convention for Interval Notation.
>
> The syntax of a version range is:

```
    version-range ::= interval | atleast
    interval ::= ( '[' | '(' ) floor ',' ceiling ( ']' | ')' )
    atleast ::= version
    floor ::= version
    ceiling ::= version
```

> *If a version range is specified as a single version, it must be interpreted as the range `[version,`∞`)`.* The default for a non-specified version range is 0, which maps to `[0.0.0,`∞`)`.
>
> Note that the use of a comma in the version range requires it to be enclosed in double quotes. For example:

```
Import-Package: com.acme.foo;version="[1.23, 2)",
    com.acme.bar;version="[4.0, 5.0)"
```

> In the following table, for each specified range in the left-hand column, a version x is considered to be a member of the range if the predicate in the right-hand column is true.

```
[1.2.3, 4.5.6)  |  1.2.3 <= x <  4.5.6
[1.2.3, 4.5.6]  |  1.2.3 <= x <= 4.5.6
(1.2.3, 4.5.6)  |  1.2.3 <  x <  4.5.6
(1.2.3, 4.5.6]  |  1.2.3 <  x <= 4.5.6
1.2.3           |  1.2.3 <= x
```

Comment: Specifications have moved to https://docs.osgi.org/specification/

Answer (score 1):

1) versionRange=1.4.0 is equivalent to [1.4.0, infinity)

2) I'd say it isn't valid, since the floor should be lower than the ceiling.

3) The next OSGi spec will define a VersionRange class, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

See RFC 175 in http://www.osgi.org/Download/File?url=/download/osgi-early-draft-2011-09.pdf. It defines an update to the version definition and also introduces a VersionRange class.

Version ranges can be empty such as your example in the second bullet. An empty version range includes no versions.