# How can I import a package at any version greater than or equal to 1.0.0 in OSGi?

Tags: osgi, version, manifest.mf

I'm trying to import an OSGi package and any version greater than or equal to `1.0.0` is valid. Basically, I just want to ensure that I don't get any `0.x` version, but other than those, any version  is acceptable. How can I allow all versions between `1.0.0` (inclusive) and infinity (unbounded).

I've tried the following:

```
com.mypackage.example;version="[1.0.0,)"
com.mypackage.example;version="[1,)"
com.mypackage.example;version="[1.0.0]"
com.mypackage.example;version="[1.0.0)"
```

I've also looked at this question: [OSGI Valid Version Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353771/osgi-valid-version-ranges). But it seems to be referencing a Java API rather than the **`MANIFEST.MF`** `Import-Package` header.

Comment: Why are you asking a series of OSGi questions and then immediately answering them yourself?

Comment: @NeilBartlett, just trying to help others with questions that I have that took a long time to figure out or are unintuitive and poorly documented. [This is encouraged by SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @NeilBartlett, it also helps me, since when I have the exact same question in the future, I'll be able to google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a version range of `[1.0.0,infinity)` for a package, just include the version number in the quotes:

```
com.mypackage.example;version="1.0.0"
```

This will allow any version greater than or equal to `1.0.0`.

Since specifying a single version number implies an unbounded/infinite range, you may be wondering how you would import a specific version of a package (and no other versions). You can do that by specifying a range from a version to itself:

```
com.mypackage.example;version="[1.3.1,1.3.1]"
```

All this information comes from the Eclipse documentation on [OSGi Concepts](https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.7.0.M01/docs/virgo-user-guide/html/ch02s02.html) (specifically the *Versioning* section).

Comment: Missing reference to the specification chapter that defines this. A link to the dead Virgo project is not exactly authoritative.

Answer (score 3):

There is already an answer which explains how this can be done, but I feel duty bound to say that **nobody should ever do this**.

Placing upper bounds on a package import is an important part of API evolution and semantic versioning. If you claim to work with all future versions then you will eventually be broken by API changes.

Moving the version of an `Export-Package` from `1.x` to `2.0` implies that a *breaking change* has been made. Methods that you rely on may no longer exist, or may behave differently. It is simply not safe to say that you will be compatible with all future versions of an API.

The correct version range to use when importing a version `1.0` API is `"[1,2)"` if you are a consumer or `"[1,1.1)"` if you are a provider.

Consumers are "typical users" of the API, for example if I write a Servlet I am a "consumer" of the Servlet API. Providers are people who provide the backing implementation for the API (e.g. TomCat). Note that this is not the same as saying that implementing an interface makes you a provider - consuming the Servlet API requires you to implement the Servlet interface.